# Missing java.beans.Introspector in Spring LibGDX Android application

Tags: java, android, spring, libgdx

I'm trying to run LibGDX based Android application, which is built with Spring Framework (not Spring for Android, but plain Spring). There is an exception:

```
ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.beans.Introspector"
```

As far as I know Android runtime does not have fully-featured java.beans package as on regular JRE.

Is there any workaround for this issue (probably some 3d-party jar with missing classes)?

I can't change package name, because AnnotationBeanNameGenerator class that using this Introspector is a part of Spring-Context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it finally appears, normal Spring (not Spring for Android) could not be run on Android, because it uses CGLIB. CGLIB can only manipulate Java byte code, but on Android there is a special Dalvik byte code.

Issue with missing `java.beans` classes could be fixed by manual adding such classes (you can use some open source JRE implementation like [Apache Harmony](https://github.com/apache/harmony) ) and passing `--core-library` option to dex.

How to pass `--core-library` option:

put following into `android` section of Gradle Android plugin configuration:

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

and add new parameter:

```
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex) {
    additionalParameters=['--core-library']
}
```